# How to refresh a page after some seconds with jquery?

Tags: jquery, refresh, delay, reload

How to refresh a page after 5 seconds with jquery?

When user clicked on a HTML tag i want to reload correct page after 5000 seconds.

i used this code but it doesn't work

```
 $(".btnclose").on("click", function (e) { 
                   location.reload().delay(5000);
                   });
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can simply use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
}, 5000);
```

Note that `setTimeout` does not guarantee exact 5 second delay. It is not very accurate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use code that I have mentioned below

```
$(".btnclose").click(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
         window.location.reload();
      }, 5000);
   });
```

Comment: If my answer is right one then I request you to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLffo8mk/):

```
$(".btnclose").on("click", function (e) { 
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload();
    }, 5000)            
});
```